# VueJS add <tr> after every 25 <tr>'s - IE DOM not recognizing <template>

Tags: internet-explorer, dom, vue.js, internet-explorer-11

This is a rather abstruse question, I'm hopeful but surprised if there is anyone with an answer to it.

I need to repeat a header row every 25 records.  **The problem is IE**.  If I put the `v-for` loop inside a `<template>` tag between tbody and tr, IE 11 "hoists" it out of the DOM to before the `<table>`, so references to `i` and `datarow` in the `<tr>` tags cause an error.

If however I move the `v-for` up to the `<tbody>`, the loop works and IE doesn't mind, but the CSS is objectionable and I can't override it on my end, and all those `<tbody>`s are semantically wrong.

So I'm left wondering, any way to "dynamically" add a `<tr>` below a looped tr using VueJS, when i = 25, 50, 75, etc.?

```
<table>
    <tbody>
    <!-- <template v-for="(datarow, i) in dataset"> does not work IE11 -->
    <tr v-for="(datarow, i) in dataset">
        <td>{{ datarow.firstname }}</td>
        <td>{{ datarow.lastname }}</td>
        <td>{{ datarow.email }}</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- I need the following every say 25 rows:
        <tr v-if="!(i % 25)"> //note it must be inside the same loop where `i` is declared though..
        <td>First</td> <td>Last</td> <td>Email</td>
        </tr>
        </template>
        -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

One alternative solution, uses computed property to re-shape the dataset then get the desired result like below demo:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    dataset: Array.from({length: 10}, (v, i) => Array.from({length: 3}, (subV, subI) => {
      return i
    }) ),
    headerOccp: 4,
    headers: ['A', 'B', 'C']
  },
  computed: {
    computedDataset: function () {
      return this.dataset.reduce((pre, cur) => {
        if(pre.length % this.headerOccp === 0) {
          pre.push({'type':'header', 'data':this.headers})
        }
        pre.push({'type':'row', 'data':cur})
        return pre
      }, [])
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.header {
  background-color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.row {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
      <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(row, rowIndex) in computedDataset" :key="rowIndex">
          <td v-for="(cell, cellIndex) in row.data" :key="cellIndex" :class="row.type">{{ cell }}</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  <h3>Data:</h3>
  <p>
    {{computedDataset}}
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I will say this is the first good example of computed properties I've seen and I'm learning from it - even though it seems a lot to cowtow to IE-11 :)